# Codefluent Potentially dangerous Request.Form value with richtext fields

Tags: codefluent

After adding the multivalue (flags) enumeration solution (which works very well, thank you) from

http://blog.codefluententities.com/tag/multi-enumeration-values/

to our MVC project  we are now getting the dreaded "Potentially dangerous Request.Form value" on richtext fields across the board that we're using to generate html with a wysiwyg editor (summernote in this case).

If I remove summernote and just submit plain text the fields work perfectly, however putting any html code into the text input generates the error.

Fortunately, the error is coming out of the code just added (above) for the multi-enumeration on line 246:

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Description="...rem ipsum <strong>dolor</stron...").

Source Error: 

Line 244:                        continue;
Line 245:
Line 246:                    Add(name, nvc[name]);
Line 247:
Line 248:                }
```

EDIT:

For clarity, here is the whole method in question:

```
            private void AddRange(NameValueCollection nvc)
        {
            foreach (string name in nvc)
            {
                // handle MultiSelectList templates
                const string listSelectedToken = ".list.item.Selected";
                const string listValueToken = ".list.item.Value";
                if (name.EndsWith(listSelectedToken))
                {
                    List<bool> bools = CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.ConvertUtilities.SplitToList<bool>(nvc[name], ',');
                    string propertyName = name.Substring(0, name.Length - listSelectedToken.Length);
                    string valueKey = propertyName + listValueToken;
                    List<string> keys = CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.ConvertUtilities.SplitToList<string>(nvc[valueKey], ',');
                    int j = 0;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (bools[j])
                        {
                            if (sb.Length > 0)
                            {
                                sb.Append(CodeFluentConfiguration.EntityKeyListSeparator);
                            }
                            sb.Append(keys[i]);
                            j++;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    Add(propertyName, sb.ToString());
                    continue;
                }

                if (name.EndsWith(listValueToken))
                    continue;

                Add(name, nvc[name]);

            }
        }
```

Have I missed something in the multi-value implementation?

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this error is related to the use of a multi-valued enumeration. In fact you post a value for the Description field that contains HTML tags (strong). By default ASP.NET prevents this and throw a validation exception.

If you expect your users to enter HTML, you must instruct ASP.NET to authorize HTML.

Change the `EntityValueProvider`

```
AddRange(context.HttpContext.Request.Unvalidated.Form); // Add Unvalidated
AddRange(context.HttpContext.Request.Unvalidated.QueryString);
```

Or use the web.config: [`validateRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.validaterequest(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`requestValidationMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<system.web>
  <pages validateRequest="false" />
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Use [`AllowHtmlAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx)

```
public class Sample
{
    [AllowHtml] 
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Or [`ValidateInputAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "Description")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sadly none of those make any difference. The Exclude option is not part of the MVC framework as far I can see, and the web.config solutions are pretty bad practise if you can possible avoid them. But I did try them to check anyway.

The code added for the multi-value (listed in the question) adds a custom model binder and a value provider, and that's where the error is being kicked up (as noted).

Comment: Only the `requestValidationMode` seems to work. In fact the error comes from `HttpValueCollection.Get` as it tries to validate the property. I edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much - specifically changing the EntityValueProvider as above solved this, without the other changes.